# ¿Por qué no da la alerta "hola" usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Por qué no da la alerta "hola" usando Javascript? Teoricamente, escribe dicho script en el body y automaticamente se ejecutaria pero no lo hace ¿por qué?

```html
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = ""
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = ""
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<script>alert('hola')<\/script>"
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Si solo tienes una etiqueta body para que usas una función pensada en devolver un nodo de elementos, mejor usa query Selector

Comment: Porqué imprimir las etiquetas javascript usando javascript? :/
No es mejor un alert()?

Answer (score 2):

El problema aquí es que le estas dando mal uso a `innerHTML`. Este atributo se usa para establecer contenido al DOM, **solo admite** sintaxis de HTML. Tu estás asignandole tokens de Javascript: `<script>alert('hola')</script>`.

**Otro error en tu código:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<script>alert('hola')<\/script>"
```

La barra invertida en el cierre de la invocación de el script no debes existir, `<\/script>`

Como ya dije, `innerHTML` toma lo ingresado como sintaxis de HTML. Entonces tu ejecución terminaría escribiendo el valor indicado en el DOM.

**El uso adecuado:**

Se pude pasar texto plano o etiquetas **HTML**:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<h1>hola</h1>"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como lograr lo que quieres:**

Si lo que deseas es conseguir la alerta, solo debes de hacer esto:

```
<body>
<script>
    alert('hola')
</script>
</body>
```

Por otro lado , hay que aclarar que las alertas no forman parte del documento (objeto `document`) si no de la ventana (objeto `Window`). Es decir las alertas ya son cosas del navegador. Si se lograra escribir en el documento (`document`, DOM) no se lograría nada.

Te dejo enlaces a la documentación de Mozilla, donde explican mejor esto:

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

[`Window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Espero que te haya servido.

Answer (score 1):

Elimina el carácter `\` de la etiqueta de cierre.

Comment: Esto perfectamente lo podías haber escrito en un comentario. ://

Comment: Perdona, pero desde la versión móvil no puedo escribir comentarios

Comment: No funciona. ¿Soluciones?

Comment: @gcoronel99 ¿Alguna solucion?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas asignando a una string un alert y por eso no te funciona, tu necesitas la funcion window.onload , que es cuando carga la pagina.
Basicamente creo que tu lo que intentas hacer es que cuando cargue pa pagina aparezca un alert y eso seria asi:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        alert('hola mundo!');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: o utilizando un `<body onload="funcion()">`